# HTML Push and Pop History

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I am very close to what I am attempting to accomplish, but I have two issues (that I know of):

1. If the user navigates away to another site (either forward or back buttons), and then comes back, the last "state" is not properly registered in the history, but any previous "states" are properly added.
2. The Div layers do not show in Firefox, unless using the forward or back navigation. Clicking to show a Div layer, you can see if for a split second, then it disappears.

HTML/JavaScript code:

```
<html> 
 <head> 
 <title>Test Nav</title> 

    <script language="JavaScript">
        function clicked(divID) {
            document.getElementById('divOne').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divTwo').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(divID).style.display = 'block';
            data = divID || null;
            history.pushState(data,'Test','\Test04.html');

            return event.preventDefault();
        }
        function updateContent(data) {
            document.getElementById('divOne').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divTwo').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(data).style.display = 'block';
            window.alert(data);
        }
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
            updateContent(event.state);
        });
        history.replaceState(data, 'Test','\Test04.html');
    </script> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <nav>
            <ul class="cf">
                <li><a href="#DivOne" onclick="clicked('divOne')">Div One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#DivTwo" onclick="clicked('divTwo')">Div Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="divOne" style="display: none">
            This is Div One
        </div>
        <div id="divTwo" style="display: none">
            This is Div Two
        </div>  
     </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: you are saying that when user navigates to another website, and then comes back, the states are no longer valid?

Comment: Just the last state/div that was displayed, prior to leaving the page. If I go back or forward 2+ in the history, then the correct state/div is displayed.

Comment: forget about div, we are talking about states here, check if the correct state is there wen user navigates back, then we can check the div not showing properly

Comment: The state is undefined. This suggests that the current state is not added to history until the user clicks to load the next state. So in this scenario, I click on DivTwo, and DivOne is added to the history (assuming Div One is what is currently displayed). If the user then navigates to a new site, Div Two needs to be added, but is not. My assumption is that history.pushState takes care of this, but it would appear that is not correct. What am I missing?

Comment: Bump...Any help as to what I'm doing wrong with this code? Some more testing has shown that the correct state is there, but still reports it is undefined. You can verify this with the following:

Comment: 1) Launch the html.  2) Click on "Div One".   3) Click on "Div Two".  4) Navigate to a new website, e.g. cnn.com.   5) Press the back button in your browser two times. You should be a "Div One" again.  6) Press the forward button in your browser, and you are back at "Div Two". The question is, how to get the right state when first returning back?